# SliderIOS – custom moveable image

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

I'm using `react-native` and for a component I need to replace the default image of the SliderIOS component with a custom one. Is there any way of accomplishing this or should I create a custom slider component? (I don't have any experience in this.)

I have already tried embedding an image as a child of the slider as well as the vice-versa approach, however non of them have worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a [pull request](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/2375) fixing this issue which hopefully gets accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [source code for RCTSliderManager](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/React/Views/RCTSliderManager.m#L50), we can see that it only exposes `value`, `maximumValue`, `minimumValue`, `minimumTrackTintColor` and `maximumTrackTintColor`. That means like it looks like you're out of luck. You could use the RCTSlider and RCTSliderManager files as a starting point for a custom component, or you could create a pull request to expose `setThumbImage` on UISlider.

Comment: Thanks, I am going to create a custom component.

Comment: Cool! If you happen to open source it, can you add it as an answer here?